# How do I add html link to image title

Tags: html, image, title

I'm actually needing to include html links in the longdesc attribute. I've altered prettyphoto to use longdesc instead of title for images, but I need to include html links in those descriptions. I know it's possible with code for characters, I just don't remember what those are.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give any example of code you want to have inside your longdesc? See http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#long-descriptions for usage of the longdesc attribute.

Comment: see http://jasondaydesign.com/masonry_demo/
the wraps on the boxes pulls from the title attribute. So I needed to alter prettyphoto to pull from somewhere else. So I used longdesc. I may try a hidden div. But I was looking for some solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with the `longdesc` attribute:

```
<img src="theimage.png" longdesc="thedescription.html" />
```

And then, in thedescription.html:

```
<a href="http://test.com/">Link</a>
```

One alternative way to do this is by using an `OBJECT` element, as follows:

```
<OBJECT data="theimage.png" type="image/png">
    <a href="http://test.com/">Link</a>
</OBJECT>
```

Also, since you asked for it, here is how to convert html entities automatically in jquery:

```
$('<div/>').text('<a href="link.html">Some Link</a>').html();
// the above evaluates to &lt;a href=&quot;link.html&quot;&gt;Some Link&lt;/a&gt;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can use [Walter Zorn's wz_tooltip](http://wztip.info/index.php/Main_Page) to show a tooltip with any kind of content.

And example of use:

```
<img src="theimage.png" onmouseover="Tip('<a href=\'http://test.com/\'>Link</a>');" onmouseout="UnTip();">
```

Answer (score 1):

[The longdesc attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longdesc_attribute) is an URI, not a place to add code. In other words, you'll need to create a page that the longdesc links to. This page is where you'll make a thorough description of what's on the image.

Comment: the reason I approached it this way was because I already have a function that pulls from the title, and I needed prettyphoto to pull the description text from somewhere else. So I used longdesc.

Comment: Using it for anything else than what it was intended for will render it useless for screen readers.

Comment: anyway then to get html into alt?

Comment: Keep in mind that `longdesc` is [no longer valid in HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/html5/#attr-img-longdesc).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the html entities?

If so, these are what you are looking for:

`&gt; = >`

`&lt; = <`

`&#34; = "`

`&#39; = '`

Comment: anyway to do a replace with jquery automatically?

Comment: You can get the contents of the londgesc with:

`jQuery("image").attr("longdesc");`

The just perform a regex to pull out the link.

Comment: See my answer below to replace entities in jquery automatically.

Comment: hmmm...great comments and answers. 
I need a lightbox that allows for html in descriptions that's can be redistributed. That's my real issue.

Comment: It's the  4th item down on the page. http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#support

Comment: And an alternative method for the same script: http://www.saurdo.com/01/03/using-html-in-a-lightbox-description

Comment: But, I need one more like prettyphoto, fancybox, etc. that can do multiple types of content.

What I really need is a port of phatfusion multibox to jquery...