# How to use a link as image title in html

Tags: html

I made attempt and tried to find my goal But I couldn't and found solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032828/how-do-i-add-html-link-to-image-title) that didn't benefit for me! 
I have `<img src="url" title="ali.com">` I want to make `ali.com` a link. I used
`title=<a href="ali.com">ALI.com</a>` but doesn't work! any way?

Comment: You should'nt use links in title!!
instead you can create some pop up's to do such kind of functionality!!

is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use url as a title (google.com?d=1&e=2 this is string) 
You need to run little js code to achieve final goal

put something like this html

```
<a class="mylink"> <img title="blahblah" scr =""></img></a>
```

and you can get title string by

```
yourtitlestring = $(".mylink img").attr("title")
```

and now you can set href of link

```
$(".mylink").setAttribute("href", yourtitlestring);
```

Answer (score 1):

The title attribute accepts only plain text, you cannot have any markup there.

If you want a tooltip with a link inside (and I'd urge you not to as it is a difficult UI to use), then you'll need to build the whole thing with JavaScript and DOM.

Comment: bring me an example please

Comment: I don't have time to build a JavaScript tooltip widget for you from scratch. Try a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers suffices your requirement, but specific to your use case :

`<a href="ali.com"> <img src="image url" title="ali.com"/>  </a>`